# Combine $ and _ to pluck by data values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I have a list of jquery elements with a data attribute.

Now I want to get a list of these data attributes.

As the `data`-attribute is some kind of an object property, I thought this might work with underscores [`pluck`](http://underscorejs.org/#pluck) method.

Is this even possible?

See this short example:

```js
var divs = $("div");

// now do something

// expected result: [1, 2, 3]
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.com/libraries/underscore.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div data-foo="1">a</div>
<div data-foo="2">b</div>
<div data-foo="3">c</div>
<div>x</div>
```

**Solution**

Based on @romeo-sierra this is the way I wrote it down (as I already have jquery objects). Underscores pluck is superfluous

```js
var foos = $("div").map(function() {
  return $(this).data("foo");
}).toArray();

console.log(foos);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-foo="1">a</div>
<div data-foo="2">b</div>
<div data-foo="3">c</div>
<div>x</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about the following, that uses pure jQuery? (since you already are using it)

```
var arr = [];
$('div[data-foo]').each(function(){
    arr.push($(this).data("foo")); // should return the value
});
console.log(arr);
```

Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hrmsq4cp/) out.

Comment: `map()` would be more fitting in this case.

Comment: Indeed, no array `arr` definition.

Comment: But his expectation says something like `// expected result: [1, 2, 3]` isn't it?

Comment: @RomeoSierra see the "solution" in the question above

Comment: @ppasler I was just editing the fiddle to what you have accomplished! :D

Comment: @RomeoSierra great thanks! Just for the record: you do not need a fiddle, as there are running examples in the stackoverflow editor.

Answer (score 7):

Vanilla JS can accomplish this just fine, no jQuery nor any other library needed:

```js
const foos = [...document.querySelectorAll('[data-foo]')]
  .map(elm => elm.dataset.foo);
console.log(foos);
```

```html
<div data-foo="1">a</div>
<div data-foo="2">b</div>
<div data-foo="3">c</div>
<div>x</div>
```

ES5 version:

```js
var foos = Array.prototype.map.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-foo]'), function(elm) {
  return elm.dataset.foo;
});
console.log(foos);
```

```html
<div data-foo="1">a</div>
<div data-foo="2">b</div>
<div data-foo="3">c</div>
<div>x</div>
```

Comment: As beautiful as this is, be aware that `[...document.querySelectorAll('[data-foo]')]` won't work in anything under IE12

Answer (score 1):

You **definitely** have to lookup for a specific data attribute.

You can't just drain the whole page for elements data attribute and obtain a complete list like that.

**But if you know what you look for...**
*See below*

```js
var attribute = "foormidable";

$("*").each(function(){
  var match = $(this).attr("data-"+attribute);
  if(typeof(match)!="undefined"){
    console.log(match);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div data-foorm="1">a</div>
<div data-foormidable="2">b</div>
<div data-foolahlayouuu="3">c</div>
<div>x</div>
```

**OR** using [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/)

```js
var attribute = "foormidable";

$("*").each(function(){
  var match = $(this).data(attribute);
  if(typeof(match)!="undefined"){
    console.log(match);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div data-foorm="1">a</div>
<div data-foormidable="2">b</div>
<div data-foolahlayouuu="3">c</div>
<div>x</div>
```

That last one will get the value of THE OBJECT... Be it dynamic via JS code.
That is real different from the on `load` markup attribute value.
;)

Comment: I am well aware that I need some better selector than `*` :)

Comment: Sure... Just for the basic demo ... Else it's a bad practice.. *«If you don't know what to shoot at... Leave the bullets out of the gun my son.»*

Comment: `$("*")` is a good debugging trick and a very bad pratice to leave on production site.